# questions about object array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am having array like bellow.I don't understand how it is created.

```
 xyz Object ( [foo] => 10 [foo1:protected] => Array ( [b] => 5 [b1] => 6 ) )
```

my questions

- What is xyz
- How can i get the value of b1
- How this array is created
- How :protected is used in array
- What is the difference between this one and normal or stdobject array

  Thanks in advance

Comment: `xyz` is an [object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), **not** an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of class `xyz` which contains fields : `foo` and `foo1`.

```
<?php
 class xyz
  {
     var $foo=10;
     protected   $foo1=array("b"=>5,"b1"=>6);
     public function getB1() { return $this->foo1["b1"];}
  }

  $a=new xyz();
  print_r($a);

// print $a->foo1["b1"]; // can't be accessible due to protection
  print $a->getB1();
?>
```

Comment: $avd :how can i extract b1 value

Comment: @gowri - protected members of class are not accessible outside the class definition. You can "encapsulate" it via a public method.

Answer (score 1):

1) I believe that is the object or class name (can't remember which).

2) You can't outside of the class unless you have a public getter for the array (it's protected).

3) It's not an array, it's an object. It is initialised somewhere in your code.

4) Protected is a class access keyword, it's not used with arrays.

5) stdClass (assuming that's what you mean) wouldn't have a set var protected (somebody correct me if that's wrong).